# How can I show this json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

In $.ajax I Get this json data.
How can show All 'a'?

```
{
    "one": "tt",
    "two": {
        "i1": {
            "id": "1",
            "a": "ff"
        },
        "i2": {
            "id": 2,
            "a": "gg"
        }
    },
    "three": "kk"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
for (var k in data.two) {
  console.log(data.two[k].a);
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/xolavu/1/edit?js,console)

**Update:**

```
$.each(data.two, function (i, value) {
  console.log(value.a);
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/xolavu/2/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way using `each`

```
{
    "one": "tt",
    "two": {
        "i1": {
            "id": "1",
            "a": "ff"
        },
        "i2": {
            "id": 2,
            "a": "gg"
        }
    },
    "three": "kk"
}

 $.each(data.two, function(i, item) {  
  alert(item.a); 
 });​
```

Comment: Or `item.a` in your example

Answer (score 1):

I think this little recursive function can help to print all the 'a' properties of the json you received.

```
function show(obj)
{
  var atts = Object.keys(obj);
  atts.forEach(function (element, index, array)
  {
   if(element=='a') console.log(obj[element]);
   show(obj[element]); // recursiveness
  });
}
```